# Although tor is the default proxy, it does not work as default!

Tags: command-line, networking, proxy, tor

I installed tor using *apt* and it started to work on port 9050 as a socks proxy automatically.

So I set my Network Proxy to be on Manual mode:

*FTP*, *HTTP*, *HTTPS*: **127.0.0.1:8118**

*SOCKS*: **127.0.0.1:9050**

I rebooted my system and I expected that my requests don't reveal my real public IP address, but they did. So I installed Foxy Proxy extension from 
the chrome webstore and set it to use the SOCKS proxy from port 9050 for requests. It worked! But I don't have any solution for using tor in terminal. I want it to be my default, and it should be!